# Задание на C++, 1 курс по программированию

Tags: c++

Напишите программу, которая выполняет следующее:

- на консоль выводится сообщение «Введите целое число от 3 до 8 : »;
- требуемое число вводится с клавиатуры, производится проверка корректности ввода;
- если ввод некорректен, то есть, если число не укладывается в диапазон [3; 8], выводится сообщение «Ввод некорректен», и программа завершает работу;
- при корректном вводе с новой строки выводится сообщение
  «Введите количество последующих чисел от 5 до 10»;
- требуемое число вводится с клавиатуры и также проверяется его корректность;
- некорректный ввод влечет сообщение «Ввод некорректен», и программа завершает работу;
- при корректном вводе запрограммировать вывод следующей строки:
  «За числом <1-й ввод> следуют <2-й ввод> чисел <последовательность чисел>»

Не получается вывести последовательность числе, подскажите плиз!)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#define PI 3.14159265
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int a;
    int b;
    cout << "Введите целое число от 3 до 8 :";
    cin >> a;
    if (a > 2 && a < 9)
    {
        cout << "Введите количество последующих чисел от 5 до 10:";
        cin >> b;
        if (b > 4 && b < 11)
        {
            cout << "За числом " << a << " следуют " << b << " чисел последовательность чисел";

            for (int i = a; i < 10; ++i) 
                cout << i << " ; ";
            cout << "За числом " << b << " следуют " << b << " чисел последовательность чисел";
            for (int m = b; m == b; ++m)
                cout << m << " ; ";
            
        }
        else {
            cout << "Ввод некорректен! Введите число в диапазоне от 5 до 10.";
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Ввод некорректен! Введите число в диапазоне от 3 до 8.";
    }

    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: В чём требуется помощь?

Comment: Подскажите как проавильно выполнить это задание, пожалуйста

Comment: Руслан, а как бы вы делали - приведите свои попытки, без попыток помочь может только преподаватель

Comment: добавил код к заданию, пробовал по разному

Answer (score 2):

Руслан, вам надо знать всего то немного:

#include - для подключения библиотек

std::cout << "%Тут текст%" - для вывода текста

std::cin >> %Тут переменная% - для ввода данных

if (условие) else - для проверки на условие

exit(status) - выход из программы

и цикл for - для вывода последовательности чисел

Если я дам вам весь разписаный код в деталях, то вы ничему не научитесь, следовательно вам просто надо подключить Google, логику и сделать это задание

Comment: вот как раз с циклом фор немного неясно) поэтому выложил, хотел поглядеть какие вообще варианты, но спасибо))